# Nodejs websocket: how to continuously send client message without server response

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, websocket

I am new to Nodejs event-based, asynchronous communication. For Websocket Client-Server communication what I have figured out till now is, after the socket connection is established, the client and the server communicates with each other based on event triggers.

On the client side I am creating a new websocket and communicating with a Nodejs server. The client side events I have till now are:

```
1. socket.on('open', function open() {}
2. socket.on('message', function message(data) {}
3. socket.on('close', function close() {}
4. socket.on('error', function error(err) {}
```

After socket is established, `socket.on('message'` gets triggered each time server is sending a response message. At present I am sending a client message to the server inside this function.

But, the server side logic is such that, client will keep sending messages continuously, which the server will accept, but may not send back a reply. Hence, `socket.on('message'` may not get triggered all the time, and hence, as per my logic I won't be able to send further messages from the client side if there is no response from the server!

The solution I tried: 
Inside `socket.on('open'`'s callback function I kept a `async.whilst()` loop to continuously send messages to the server. Outside the `socket.on('open'` I am keeping rest of the events as listed above.

But, when I am running the code, all messages from the client side are going sequentially one after another, but `socket.on('message'` is not getting triggered at all. From the server logs I have confirmed that server is sending messages correctly.

From this behavior it seems, the while loop is actually behaving like a blocking while loop, which I don't want! What am I doing wrong here?

I won't be able to paste the entire source code I have due to confidentiality issue, but I am pasting my `socket.on('open'` body with the `async.whilst()` loop. Also, I am adding the place holders for the other events.

Here is the code:

```
 var count=10;
 socket.on('open', function open() {

    async.whilst(
        function () { return count>=0; },
        function (callback) {
                console.log("Allowed to send msgs? YES");       
                senddataToServer(socket); //This function sends data to server using a callback function to catch error, hence asynchronous.
                count--;
                callback();
        },
        function (err) {
            console.log("Allowed to send msgs? NO");    
            socket.close();
        }
    ); 
  });

socket.on('message', function message(data) {}
socket.on('close', function close() {}
socket.on('error', function error(err) {}

senddataToServer(socket){}
```

I got the code for `async.whilst` from this link: [whilst(test, fn, callback)](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst)

Comment: don't send inside the message event, send from outside as needed, not just once every message.

Comment: I don't know how to continuously send from 'outside as needed'. That's why I tried an alternate solutions with async.whilst(). Please check the 'solution I tried' section. That part is also not working. Hence, I posted this question. Thanks!

Comment: it's really simple, in your code: `socket.send("hello world");` runs anywhere. ex: `setInterval(function(){socket.send(+new Date);}, 1000);` i don't see any need for the async library at all from what's shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide what you want to trigger the client sending new data to the server.  You should not be using the incoming arrival of a message from the server to trigger a client send that has nothing to do with the incoming server message.

Your options for triggering a client send are:

1. Use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` to send something to the server on a regular time interval (e.g. every 30 seconds).
2. Respond to some event in the client and use that as a trigger for sending your data to the server (such as a button click, a mouse movement, data arriving, etc...).

If you would be more specific about what you're trying to send to the server and when it is appropriate to send it to the server, we could advise much more specifically about how to best schedule or trigger the sends.

Comment: Client will start sending "Hello" to the server as soon as the websocket connection is established. The first "Hello" from the server will trigger the start of processing some internal logic and won't send any reply back to the client until the internal processing is over. Once, the processing is over, server will send a response back to the client. But, meanwhile, The client will continuously send "Hello" and won't stop.

Comment: @kajarigd - but why send meaningless "hello" messages from client to server.  A client should NOT be just spinning in a tight loop sending as many messages to the server as possible.  That's ridiculously inefficient and doesn't appear to actually accomplish anything.  If the client was running on a battery powered device (e.g. a tablet or smartphone), it would deplete the battery pretty quickly.  And, it would be using meaningless bandwidth for both client and server internet connection.  If you describe the problem you're REALLY trying to solve, we can help, but we need real info.

Comment: Actually, I explained to you my requirement with the 'Hello' example. Once a websocket is created, server's job is to monitor the browser activities of the client (mouse movement, click, keyword type, etc). Based on what kind of activities the client is doing, the server will send a response. The server code is not in my control, and hence I don't know exactly which of the browser activities are meaningful and on what condition. Hence, my job is to write a code where the client will continuously send browser activities to the server. Server will reply on when needed.

Comment: @kajarigd - Then the browser should send data ONLY when a browser activity occurs.  Hook up event handlers for the browser events that you wish to monitor and send that data to the server when you get it.  Use the browser's event system to trigger the events for you and when you have some data, then send it to the server.

Comment: You are right. When I am actually working with the browser, this is working fine. Now, I want to automate these browser movements. I want to do a load testing on the browser with multiple socket creation. Each socket will represent a client on the browser. I don't know how to simulate manual browser activities into automatic function calls. Hence, I was thinking if there is a way to trigger an event from the client nodejs javascript code, my job will be done!

Comment: If you see the second part of my post above. I tried to simulate that part using asyc.whilst(). But it seems it is working like a blocking loop because socket.on('message', event is not getting triggered at all.

Comment: @kajarigd - for automating and load testing, please ask a new question and describe that problem in detail (I don't follow at all what you are trying to do there).  I think I've answered the question you originally asked here.  StackOverflow does not work well if you keep trying to add more to your question.  Instead, get an answer to what you originally asked and then ask a new question.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But, I don't want to design a load tester right now. I just want to trigger client message send continuously, and I don't want to trigger it with manual browser clicks. That's all I want to do. You asked me why I am doing this meaningless thing. That's why I was explaining. I don't need any help here to create a load tester.

Comment: @kajarigd - Then use `setInterval()` to trigger a function regularly (e.g. every 5 seconds) and set the time interval to whatever delay you want between messages.  That was already suggested in my answer.  You have to give the browser some delay between messages to allow it to do its normal housekeeping.

Comment: Yes! Actually, I am already trying that. I am trying to figure out inside which method I should put the setInterval() method. Will it be inside socket.on('open') or somewhere else. I will respond to this post with my results. I understand you asked me so many questions, because you wanted to give me a more requirement specific solution, which could have been more efficient. I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: @kajarigd - I don't follow the exact sequence of events, but I assume you would put the `setInterval()` function call as soon as you know the webSocket is up and running and ready for data to be sent (which is probably in the "open" event).  You do need to make sure the `setInterval()` is only called once though so you don't get double intervals running.